# Form validation not working in ie8 or 7

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Hi basically i can't seem to get the form validation to work on my form in ie8 or below. It works absolutely fine every where else though.

Basically its along these lines:

```
function validateform() {
    if (document.getElementById('firstinput').value == '') {
        alert("Select start Date");
        document.getElementById('firstinput').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('secondinput').value == '') {
        alert("Select end Date");
        document.getElementById('secondinput').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('restriction').checked == false) {
        alert('Please select I have read and understand the above restrictions.');
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('termscondition').checked == false) {
        alert('Please select terms and condition..');
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('letters_code').value == '') {
        alert("Enter captcha code..");
        document.getElementById('letters_code').focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}​
```

Just wondered if there are any obvious mistakes that i can't see :s thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: what happens when it fails, any error messages ? whats supposed to happen ? how is this method called ?

Comment: I dont get any error messages but i have two different sets of feedback. The client is saying that he gets a pop up but when he click ok, instead of having to check the terms box he is just sent through to the next page, but when i try it in ie tester i dont get any pop up and it takes me straight through.

Comment: I suggest you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ of the whole page - this will make it easier to debug ... what you have at the moment (in your question) looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

Editing because i phased this terribly!

I have encountered an issue involving a submit button being named submit, that only failed in IE, and not in firefox/chrome, if you could make sure that is not the issue, that would help!

Alternatively, more information would be helpful, as there does not appear to be anything wrong with the code posted

Comment: I am aware this does not apear to have anything to do with the above, but if the submission fails, so does the validation.

Comment: There is a problem across all browsers when trying to call `form.submit()` on a form with a form control named `submit`, but there is no indication in the question that that is happening here. The problem in the linked to document is that something was styled to cover up the submit button.

Comment: Huh.. good point, didnt read the link well enough. But I have had this not actually fail in firefox and chrome but fail in IE, with a form.submit call. A Major indication was the fact that my validation stopped working. As for indicating this may be an issue, simply that I cannot find any error in the above code and way trying for an alternate solution. Thanks for your comment though

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for having a look at this for me. The button is named submit:  <input type="submit" class="Submitbook" value="Continuer au Paiment" name="submit" onclick="return validateform();"  /> so i have tried renaming it to something else but the button still took me through to the next page without having to check the terms and condition box?